# postgresql: offset + limit gets to be very slow

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, limit, offset

I have a table `tmp_drop_ids` with one column, `id`, and 3.3 million entries. I want to iterate over the table, doing something with every 200 entries. I have this code:

```
LIMIT = 200
for offset in xrange(0, drop_count+LIMIT, LIMIT):
    print "Making tmp table with ids %s to %s/%s" % (offset, offset+LIMIT, drop_count)
    query = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_cur_drop_ids; CREATE TABLE tmp_cur_drop_ids AS
    SELECT id FROM tmp_drop_ids ORDER BY id OFFSET %s LIMIT %s;""" % (offset, LIMIT)
    cursor.execute(query)
```

This runs fine, at first, (~0.15s to generate the tmp table), but it will slow down occasionally, e.g. around 300k tickets it started taking 11-12 seconds to generate this tmp table, and again around 400k. It basically seems unreliable.

I will use those ids in other queries so I figured the best place to have them was in a tmp table. Is there any better way to iterate through results like this?

Comment: Do you have tmp_drop_ids indexed? 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tmp_drop_ids_id_uidx ON tmp_drop_ids (id);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a cursor instead. Using a OFFSET and LIMIT is pretty expensive - because pg has to execute query, process and skip a OFFSET rows. OFFSET is like "skip rows", that is expensive.

[cursor documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-declare.html)

Cursor allows a iteration over one query.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM big_table;
FETCH 300 FROM C; -- get 300 rows
FETCH 300 FROM C; -- get 300 rows
...
COMMIT;
```

Probably you can use a server side cursor without explicit using of DECLARE statement, just with support in [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) (search section about server side cursors).

Comment: i ended up doing this from python (using cursor object's `fetchmany`).

Answer (score 2):

If your id's are indexed you can use "limit" with ">", for example in python-like pseudocode:

```
limit=200
max_processed_id=-1
query ("create table tmp_cur_drop_ids(id int)")
while true:
  query("truncate tmp_cur_drop_ids")
  query("insert into tmp_cur_drop_ids(id)" \
        + " select id from tmp_drop_ids" \
        + " where id>%d order by id limit %d" % (max_processed_id, limit))
  max_processed_id = query("select max(id) from tmp_cur_drop_ids")
  if max_processed_id == None:
    break
  process_tmp_cur_drop_ids();
query("drop table tmp_cur_drop_ids")
```

This way Postgres can use index for your query.